# CPU information meaning

Tags: cpu

I wanted to know some information of my cpu and I got this output(Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 stepping 13) from the input of wmic cpu get caption.
Please what does Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 stepping 13 means?

Comment: Instead of trying to put the puzzle together for you.  What Intel CPU do you have specifically?

Comment: "I got this output" from where? surely that wasn't all it told you, so where's the rest of the info? and did you try to use a search engine first to find out what the unfamiliar words mean? this is not a good question.

Answer (score 7):

The output is the technical version of the processor.
**Intel 64** - Indicates it is a 64-bit processor
**Family 6** - Not entirely sure what constitutes a family for Intel (Possible like the Core family. Core i7, Core 2, etc)
**Model 15** - CPU Model number (6000 Series)
**Stepping 13** - Revision number. A minor change to the CPU model.

A quick google search of the version information pointed me to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_microprocessors) which indicates it is a Core 2 Duo T5470.
You would get a much easier to read CPU version by using 'name' instead of 'caption'. Examples:
CPU caption on my machine - Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3
CPU name - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz

Comment: Family 6 is probably referring to the 6-series chipsets from Intel.